# Switchable nvidia GT 540m HDMI output Problem

Tags: nvidia, monitor, hdmi, displayport

I have bought a Alienware m11xr3 with nvidia GT 540m and a internal graphic card.

```
uname -r
3.2.0-33-generic-pae
```

here is the `lspci | grep VGA` output:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev ff)
```

So far so good. the Geforce is recognized and i can use it through optirun:

```
optirun glxspheres 
Polygons in scene: 62464
Visual ID of window: 0x21
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 540M/PCIe/SSE2


glxspheres 
Polygons in scene: 62464
Visual ID of window: 0x9e
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
```

Here the files from /etc/bumblebee

bumblebee.conf

```
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=true
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-current
Module=nvidia
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau



xorg.conf.nouveau
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen         "Screen0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nouveau"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
EndSection

xorg..conf.nvidia
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device1"
    Driver "nvidia"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP"
EndSection

xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 256mm x 144mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Now there are several problems:

1) Bumblebee seems not going off, when i close a application running in optirun. Remains on "ON"

2) The HDMI output doesnt work at all. means, i cant really say if there is a reaction, when i plugin the hdmi cable. obviously there is nothing displayed.

3) Cant find cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf!

4) I got also a DisplayPort and thought of using this, but havent got an adapter yet. maybe with this it works?

Honestly i am realtively new to Linux/Ubuntu. I am working about half a year with ubuntu, so i am not a professional, but i can do basic stuff without problems and follow guides.

Would be very nice if we can solve the problem. there are many m11xr3 Users who have this problem and i guess its not impossible to get hdmi/Displayport(?) working.
If you need any other informations please let me know!
Thanks for your time and help!

Okay an udpate from my side.

Now i can use the hdmi output in a not very handy way.
What i did: As I wrote in my last comment, i have reinstalled Ubuntu with the linlap guide. 
Then i found [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/get-hdmi-working-with-nvidia-optimus-on.html) [two](http://itviking.net/blog/m11xr3-bumblebee-and-the-dual-screen-setup) usefull guides.

Now it works like [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-huJF-cXnI).

Hope I could help someone with this solution, but for me the mainproblem is, that you cant clone your Desktop, you need to install another Desktop Environment. Any ideas how to improve the script to use unity on both displays?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should file bug report.
2. Few lines from bumblebee wiki

   > Optimus laptops have two video chips: an integrated Intel and a
   >   discrete nVidia one. If the port (DisplayPort / HDMI / VGA) is wired
   >   to the Intel chip, you do not need to do anything special to get
   >   external monitors to work.
   >
   > When the port is wired into the nvidia chip, you can currently not expand the screen over monitors. The monitor may still be used as
   >   extra screen (with no desktop running on it) or to run the full
   >   desktop on it (with no output on the Intel LVDS output, a.k.a. "the
   >   laptop display").

   I don't know which type of wiring you have. Power management need to be disabled.
   You can [read more over here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup)
3. Bumble doesn't use normal xorg.conf file. The config file is this one (as per your question)  `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau`

So it will be better to read the **issues and wiki** from [this github project page](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Okay so ill post a bugreport of bumblebee as soon as possible.
I already read the link for your answer of question 2. I know that the GT540m is wired to the external displayports, at least the HDMI, so i guess also the Displayport(?).
As you can see i have tried to make the changes written there, but with no effect.

Okay so question 3 is solved. it wanst clear to me where the xorg.conf file was.

Comment: What about this? http://www.linlap.com/alienware_m11x  the guide is made for mandriva distribution, anything i should modify for ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Go ahead. Hopefully it will work. I would recommend to unistall bumblebee completely and reinstall. (Better to start with a fresh ubuntu install). I have a nvidia 540m gpu, I re installed ubuntu several times while playing around old bumblebee (the obsolete one by MrMee) and this new bumblebee